# Fill labels when user select drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know how to fill set of labels when user select two drop down list which gives year and month?

Comment: May be a little more proper description of problem and some code will help.

Comment: How did you specify the format of month & year in drop down's and is there any specific format to be displayed on labels?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by a "set of labels", but if you just want combobox values something like this will work.

```
label1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue + "/" + comboBox2.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

set `SelectedIndexChanged` of both `DropDownList` items to below

```
    protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = string.Format("Year :{0}, Month :{1}" , DropDownListYear.SelectedValue, DropDownListMonth.SelectedValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an event for **DropDownList** named, **SelectedIndexChanged**. you can use this to fill your set of labels. since you have 2 dorpdowns here, you gota do something like:

```
    protected void DropDownYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* code to check if the user has selected the year */
        label1.Text = "your string";
        label2.Text = "your other string";

    }
```